# How to bin values, while ignoring others that fulfill a certain criteria in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, binning

My Dataframe consists of non-negative values except for missing values which have been encoded as negative. So I want to bin on every column while excluding the negative values.

So far `qcut` on `[df>0]` puts Nan where previously there were negative values, and that is not what I want as I want to retain those values(they have meaning).

```
dat[i]=pd.qcut(dat[i][dat[i]>0], 10,labels = False, duplicates='drop')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What do you mean by "retain those values"?  Do you want to retain them in the binned version of the dataframe, or just in the original dataframe?  Can you maybe show us a (small!) sample of the input and the desired output?

Comment: Since the values are already encoded, they are already binned and have meaning, so I want them to remain as is, then bin on the non-negative . An example is if we have a column with values 0-100, and missing values as -3. I want to keep the -3 where it is , but bin the 100 values into 10 distinct categories.

Comment: I'm not totally sure I follow you - a small "toy" example (like with five rows and one column) of both your desired input and desired output would make what you want a lot clearer.

Comment: B           
0  7  
1  8  
2  4  
3  5  
4  5 
5 -4  
 So we can bin to 3 categories (4,5), (6,7), (8,9), leaving us with:
   B  
0 2
1  3
2  1
3  1 
4  1
5 -4

Comment: Putting the sample in the question itself (in a way that can be easily pasted into code) will make it easier for people to answer.  At the moment it's still hard to tell what your input and output are.  And how do you want the bins to be determined?  Do you actually want to use qcut?  Because when I run qcut it doesn't produce the neat bins you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired input and output are still a little unclear to me (putting them into the question would probably help).  But I think you can achieve what you want simply by creating a temporary column and filling the NaN values with the original column.

Starting with your original `qcut` code, but assigning it to a new column:

```
dat['temp'] = pd.qcut(dat[i][dat[i]>0], 10, labels=False, duplicates='drop')
dat[i] = dat['temp'].fillna(df[i])
del df['temp']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is precisely what I needed.